# Converting EntrezID to Gene names

Tags: r, genetics, rna-seq

I am trying to convert my Ensembl genes to their gene names using org.Hs.eg.db.

However, whenever I try, it gives me the error:
select()' returned 1:many mapping between keys and columns

I've tried to look at other posts but am not understanding as to why this is happening? Any advice would be really appreciated!

```
genesymbols<- mapIds(org.Hs.eg.db, keys=rownames(data), column = "SYMBOL", keytype = "ENSEMBL")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the message `select()' returned 1:many mapping between keys and columns` is an error. My understanding is that you have some Ensembl IDs which match to multiple gene names in the database and hence the error.